# Cambiar icono boton ver carrito wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, icono

Hola a todos espero que estén bien.
Por favor necesito de su ayuda con el siguiente caso:
En una tienda online creada con el tema OceanWP, luego de darle click al botón "Añadir al carrito" que esta debajo de cada producto, aparece un nuevo botón que dice "Ver carrito [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] " con un icono de una bolsa como esta.
Yo lo que necesito es cambiar ese icono por un carrito de compra para que sea coherente con el texto.
Ya intenté con el editor de Elementor y con un código como este:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'cambiar_text');
add_filter('ngettext', 'cambiar_text');

function cambiar_text($translated) {
    $translated = str_ireplace('Ver carrito fa-bag-shopping', 'Ver carrito fa-cart-shopping', $translated);
    return $translated;
}
```

Pero creo que estoy equivocado.
Les agradezco mucho su ayuda.

**NOTA**: Yo no soy el creador de la página. El dueño me pidió que le hiciera algunas actualizaciones y cambios.

Comment: Y como pone los iconos OceanWP?? de esa misma manera debes cambiarlo, yo creo que eso esta en el área de personalizar el sitio. Y como sabrás, sin tener acceso a esa área es difícil ayudarte.